# What WPF control to use instead of ItemsControl to create a canvas with freely placeable items bound to a ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm working on a GUI where the user can place items on a canvas as he wishes and work with those items. Currently I solved this with an `ItemsControl` as follows:

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding PlacementConfiguration.EquipmentPlacementList}" Background="AliceBlue" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Canvas/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Position.X}"/>
            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Position.Y}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Width="150" Height="100" BorderThickness="3">
                <Border.BorderBrush>
                    <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0" >
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.1"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Transparent" Offset="0.9"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0.9"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Border.BorderBrush>
                <Label Content="TestLabel, Content will be presented here!"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

So the items are bound to a collection in the viewmodel. Each item is represented by a class instance with several properties and option. The issue with the solution above is that `ItemsControl` items are not selectable, which is a functionality I need.

The solution i thought was either that there is an alternative to `ItemsControl` that gives me the same freedom while at the same time having the ability to make items selectable, or to solve it manually using different mouse events.

Question, which solution is more feasible...or maybe if there is a completely other (better) way to go about such a issue.

Comment: ListBox is a Selector ItemsControl

Comment: @ASh testing out `ListBox` (and I have also tested `ListView` but with the code above I get an exception "A style intended for type 'ContentPresenter' cannot be applied to type 'ListBoxItem'. I have to look into what is causing this exception

Comment: apply style to ListBoxItem, which is ItemContainer for ListBox

Comment: Ahhh, actually quite obvious, that did it - thanks for helping!